# How do I access the template variables in a PHPunit test in Symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

I'm trying to write tests for a controller and rather than be dependent on the output HTML (which a front-end developer will no doubt tinker with) I want to make sure that the front-end developer has all the data they need.

How do I access the array of data that is handed to the template in a PHPUnit test so that I can verify it? I've trawled the web (incl. SO) and docs to no avail.

I know I could fake the call to the controller rather than use the web crawler, but is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are high level code. You should not try to write unit tests directly to controller methods. As controllers wire all low level classes, you should focus on unit testing these classes. If you have some business logic inside controller that needs testing, you should consider refactoring this action.

So my suggestion would be to use functional tests to test your controllers and use unit-tests to test your models and your business logic stuff.

If you struggle with functional tests, you can read the following:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests
- http://blog.sznapka.pl/fully-isolated-tests-in-symfony2/